# Exporting fusion charts to pdf or jpg or png in asp.net in my local PC

Tags: c#, fusioncharts

Chart is rendered in browser i want to export please tell me step by step instructions on
Server-side fusion chart exporting feature a separate setup and implementation how to do it please tell in detail

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please post some sample of your code and then describe what you get and what you wanted. They way you asked you question is very difficult to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding the following code in web.config and check:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This is required, as when you export a chart it POST SVG xml string to the server, hence ASP.NET parser throws error.

Comment: I have two web.config one is inside exporthandlers folder in which i should change

Comment: Try first with the root web.config if it does not work then go for 2nd one under 'exporthandlers'.